# Bordes/Espacios en blanco HTML

Tags: html, css

Pongo esta imagen y me salen esos bordes blancos alrededor, quisiera que se ajuste al 100% de la pantalla, sin esos bordes blancos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Prueba</title>
  <style>
    .imagen {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <img src="img_main.jpg" class="imagen" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Es por que el body viene por defecto con un margin: 8px; debes agregarle en tu css al body un margin: 0px;

Comment: Esa fue la solución.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como bien dijeron, todos los navegadores no son iguales y tienen diferentes medidas como default. Lo mejor es hacer un [reset](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) de los estilos y arrancar como si fueran todos el mismo, reiniciando los valores de la mayoría de los tag.

#### `Reset.css`:

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Luego puedes agregar ese archivo `reset.css` a tu archivo html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Prueba</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset.css" />
    <style>
    .imagen
    {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <img src="img_main.jpg" class="imagen"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: y cuando agregue otro CSS no habrá problemas?

Comment: No, siempre y cuando lo agregues después del `reset.css`.

Answer (score 0):

Los navegadores tienen reglas básicas de margin y padding así que tienes que ponerlos en 0 para eliminar los bordes.

```
body, img{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```